# Query that fetchs average values over timestamp range of time, on a certain value of another pair of fields

Tags: performance, index, postgresql-9.5, timestamp, date

This is the situation, over the time our table reached around 800 millions rows. And it is going to get bigger and bigger. It is a service that collects metrics of energy (voltage, power, current, etc) from devices in factories and warehouses. Each row has:

- a timestamp value, which is a BIGINT
- a deviceid, which is a varchar (I know, this is not good)
- a metricid, which is a varchar too
- a recvalue, which is a float (this is what we want)

Other fields not important, that need to be removed.

The table is so big that performing a query with dates in a range of one month, retrieves more than 900000 records in the result set.

```
select recvalue 
from devicesmetrics 
where deviceid = 'adpackca2_t_axm' 
  and metricid = 'EP_TOTAL_kWh' 
  and timestamp between 1532571651000 and 1537509599000;
```

Of course that takes a lot! Several minutes. Even though we already created an index like this:

```
create index dm_deviceid_metricid_timestamp 
    on devicesmetrics (deviceid, metricid, timestamp)
```

And also, the explain plan says that the query is using it.

We expected that. The solution we found was to retrieve averages of recvalue, retrieving only a certain number of points over the time. So, for example, for a month, we decided to use a query like this:

`select max("timestamp") as time_metric, metricid, deviceid, avg(cast(recvalue as float)), avg(cast(calcvalue as float))
from devicesmetrics where deviceid = 'adpackca2_t_axm' 
and metricid = 'EP_TOTAL_kWh' 
and "timestamp" between 1532571651000 and 1537509599000
group by deviceid, metricid, "timestamp"/((1537509599000-1532571651000)/1000)`

This is still taking a lot, unfortunately, around 2 minutes. Even though the number of records retrieve is lower than 500.

Suggestions on how to get a better solutions for this?

It is a standard-4 Heroku-PostgreSQL instance (~30GB RAM and 500 connections).
As another detail, I can show how the explain (analize, buffers) looks like, for that last query:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=75179.55..75561.41 rows=38182 width=62) (actual time=108265.296..108445.322 rows=802 loops=1)
  Group Key: deviceid, metricid, (("timestamp" / '4937948'::bigint))
  Buffers: shared hit=8765 read=228254
  I/O Timings: read=107118.279
  ->  Sort  (cost=75179.55..75198.64 rows=38189 width=58) (actual time=108265.172..108277.890 rows=237853 loops=1)
        Sort Key: (("timestamp" / '4937948'::bigint))
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 39593kB
        Buffers: shared hit=8765 read=228254
        I/O Timings: read=107118.279
        ->  Index Scan using dm_deviceid_metricid_timestamp on devicesmetrics  (cost=0.14..74598.28 rows=38189 width=58) (actual time=2.677..108082.026 rows=237853 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (((deviceid)::text = 'adpackca2_t_axm'::text) AND ((metricid)::text = 'EP_TOTAL_kWh'::text) AND ("timestamp" >= '1532571651000'::bigint) AND ("timestamp" <= '1537509599000'::bigint))
              Buffers: shared hit=8765 read=228254
              I/O Timings: read=107118.279
Planning time: 0.220 ms
Execution time: 108448.051 ms
```

Comment: Sorry, @ a_horse_with_no_name , I was using a short period of time. I edited the query to analize: now it takes those 108 seconds to run. After running that execution plan with analize and buffer (they actually executed the query to take the statistics), if I run it again it takes less than 3 seconds. I guess the cache system of Postgres is working fine at least.

Comment: You are obviously limited by the performance of your I/O system. The Index scan had to read 1.9GB and needed nearly 2 Minutes for that. That's a throughput of 16MB per Second if I'm not mistaken - that's horribly slow. Most probably that throughput is limited by your Heroku configuration.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I understand. Do you think there is another improvement is possible to do? Of course I will dig more into I/O limitations on Heroku. I hope I can change that.